# Open linked page in dialog, close without callback

Tags: 2010

sorry if this has been asked before:

I've used the example code from here: http://sharethepunto.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/how-to-create-pop-up-dialog.html

To open a linked page as a popup in SharePoint 2010.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
function OpenDialog(strPageURL)
{
  var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    url: dialogUrl,
    allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
    showClose: dialogShowClose,
    width: dialogWidth,
    height: dialogHeight,
    title: dialogTitle,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult) 
    { 
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult) 
    }
 }

// Dialog close event capture function
function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target)
{
  if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) // Perform action on Ok.
{
alert("User clicked Ok!");
}
 if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) // Perform action on Cancel.
 {
   alert( "User clicked Cancel!");
   }
}

</script>
<a onclick="OpenDialog('http://bing.com');">open dialog</a>​
```

My issue is, when I close the dialog, I get a callback that says:

```
Message from webpage:
Closing Dialogue
```

Which I don't want and is intrusive. All I'd like to happen is, on click, the linked page appears as a pop-up and, when closed, it closes.

I know the callback options can be altered, but I can't for the life of me find out how to achieve the above.

I've also tried simply deleting that bit of code to no avail.

Thank you in advance, everyone.